# how to verify the static route of a particular interface using ansible

Tags: ansible

I am writing an ansible task to verify the static route  configuration.

I wrote the below code and stored the output of route -n to route_result.

```
- name: check static routes
  shell: route -n 
  register: route_result
```

but I m not sure how to verify the static route of a particular interface from this result.

output of route -n is below:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         11.122.133.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.17.17.0      0.0.0.0        255.255.255.0    U     0      0        0 eth1
19.25.19.254   12.1.12.1       255.255.255.255  UGH   0      0        0 eth0
12.18.11.0     12.1.12.1       255.255.255.0    UG    0      0        0 eth0
12.18.12.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0    U     0      0        0 eth0
```

I should check that if iface is eth0 then destination is 19.25.19.254 and gateway is 12.1.12.1

Answer (score 0):

```
---

- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  become: false
  vars:
    route: 8.8.4.1
    gw: 192.168.1.2
    iface: enp0s25
  tasks:
    - command: ip route list exact {{ route }}
      register: result
      check_mode: false
      changed_when: false
      failed_when: _route not in result.stdout.strip()
      vars:
        _route: "{{ '%s via %s dev %s' | format(route, gw, iface) }}"
```

Comment: Maybe `assert` task after *command* task would be better...